# Upper bound $\frac{z^{3/2}}{1 + z^3}$

Tags: complex-analysis, upper-lower-bounds

I need to show that he upper bound of $\frac{z^{3/2}}{1 + z^3} = 0$ when $R \to \infty$, where $z = R(cos\theta +i sin\theta)$

I'm trying to use the estimation lemma, but the power of 3 confuses me.

$$|\frac{z^{3/2}}{1 + z^3}| = |\frac{R^{3/2}e^{3i\theta/2}}{1 + R^3e^{i3\theta}}| $$

because of the complex conjugate

$$\frac{|R^{3/2}e^{3i\theta/2}|}{|1 + R^3e^{i3\theta}|} = \frac{R^{3/2}}{|1 + R^3e^{i3\theta}|} $$

However, since I have $R^3$, I can't just take it out of the absolute value.

Any help will be appreciate.

Comment: Hint: $\,\left|1 + R^3e^{i3\theta}\right| \ge \Big|R^3 \left|e^{i3\theta}\right| - 1\Big|\,$.

Comment: Note the triangle inequality. Obviously $|1+a|\le|1|+|a|$ (not directly helpful), but also $|b|=|-1+1+b|\le|-1|+|1+b|$, so $|1+b|\ge|b|-1$, and this should be helpful.

Comment: I think I found what I was looking for, thanks. I didn't know the triangle inequality could work in this situation.